# Excel Checkbox DoubleClick event

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet, basically a to-do list that has checkpoints marked by checkboxes. Rules for the checkboxes are: 
1) Only the first checkbox (named checkbox_1) can be checked first.
2) Checkboxes can only be checked sequentially (i.e. checkbox_1, checkbox_2, checkbox_3 etc.)

Initially all checkboxes except for checkbox_1 are disabled. When an enabled checkbox is clicked, the next checkbox becomes enabled and disables the previous one.

The trouble I am having now is that double-clicking bypasses the `enabled` status of the checkbox and will go ahead and check the checkbox via the event handler.

How can I prevent this? Do I need to write something in the `_BeforeDoubleClick` event handler?

My event handler for the checkbox_click event is here:

```
Public Sub CheckBoxClick(Optional checkboxName As String = "")
'This calls the checkbox function to create the timestamp and enable the next visible checkbox
Dim assocTime As Range
Dim callerName As String
Dim aCaller As Variant
Dim check_num As String
Dim aCheckboxes As Variant

Set aCheckboxes = common.GetSheet(1).CheckBoxes

If checkboxName <> "" Then
    callerName = checkboxName
Else
    callerName = Application.Caller
End If

aCaller = Split(callerName, "_")
check_num = aCaller(1)

Set assocTime = common.GetRange("time_" & check_num)

If assocTime.value = "" Then
    Call obj.ClickCheckBox(callerName, Constants.mypw)
End If

If check_num = aCheckboxes.count Then
    If MainSheetFunctions.HasRedCells Then
        common.MessageBox ("This batch record has cells with errors. Please address all red cells before continuing.")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

The `obj.ClickCheckBox` sub will write the current time in an adjacent cell, and enable the next checkbox.

Thank you for your time,